# Magento2.3 : Unit Case writing for Observers

Tags: magento2.3, event-observer, unit-tests

I was wondering what is best practice for Unit test case writing for observers ?
I looked for examples in core , and found below file

```
 magento/module-sales/Test/Unit/Observer/AssignOrderToCustomerObserverTest.php
```

I found even there are no assertions are performed but when we run test case for it

```
Time: 1.6 seconds, Memory: 10.00MB

OK (1 test, 3 assertions)
```

if someone can even point me to reference article it would be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling any method with expects **once()** will increase your invoke count by one. 
You can find reference in `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase` class :

```
/**
     * Returns a matcher that matches when the method is executed exactly once.
     *
     * @return InvokedCountMatcher
     */
    public static function once()
    {
        return new InvokedCountMatcher(1);
    }
```

Please check **verifyMockObjects** function from same file, it increase count of assertion depending on method  invoked count.